# How do I add a custom template to my feature?

Tags: 7, theming, features

I have a feature with a few views. How to I add a custom template file to it?

Edit: Based on sheena_d and schnippy's suggestions, here is my entire .module code. (It is still not working)

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Code for the Nigel Gallery feature.
 */

include_once('nigel_gallery.features.inc');


function nigel_gallery_init() {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'nigel_gallery') . '/nigel_gallery.css');
}

$theme_registry['template_file'] = array(
  'template' => drupal_get_path('module', 'nigel_gallery').'/templates/views-view--gallery-content.tpl.php',
  'type' => 'module',
);
```

Comment: a custom template for your content type or for the views that you have created?

Comment: for the view. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code added to your .module file should do the trick:

```
function nigel_gallery_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {    
$theme_registry['views_view__gallery_content'] = array(
      'template' => drupal_get_path('module', 'nigel_gallery').'/templates/views-view--gallery-content.tpl.php',
      'type' => 'module',
    );
}
```

For more information, take a look at the documentation for [hook_theme_registry_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).

Comment: I have modified the above code, flushed cache, but it still no worky :(

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using? The syntax for adding something to the theme registry has changed between 6 and 7.

Comment: I am using D7. I have modified my code above to include everything 'as is' in my .module file (just to make sure I have it right. :) )

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer to be more thorough and exact for your situation :)

Comment: Tried this out and it didn't work because it needs the preprocess functions in order to render the view.  'preprocess functions' => array(
     0 => 'template_preprocess',
     1 => 'template_preprocess_views_view',
   ), Also, tpl.php isn't added to drupal_get_path function.

Comment: cannot make it working with function amu_feature_focus_front_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
 $theme_registry['views-view-fields--focus-front--block'] = array(
   'template' =>  drupal_get_path('module', 'amu_feature_focus_front').'/templates/views-view-fields--focus-front--block.tpl.php',
   'type' => 'module',
   'preprocess functions' => array( 0 => 'template_preprocess', 1 => 'template_preprocess_views_view')
 ); !?

Answer (score 0):

For either content-type or views templates, you're going to need to manually add these to your features set since ctools exports doesn't handle these. In your features folder (ex. testfeature), you want to create a subfolder for templates:

```
/testfeature
    testfeatures.features.inc
    testfeatures.info
    testfeatures.module
    templates/
```

and then copy all of your custom templates into this folder. Then in the testfeatures.module folder, you just need to use hook_theme_registry_alter to add your content-type templates in:

```
function testfeatures_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    $theme_registry['template-file']['path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_feature')."/templates/";
}
```

For views templates, you should have more success using a hook_theme function, ex:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function nigel_gallery_theme() {
  return array(
    'views-view--gallery-content' => array(
      'variables' => array('view' => NULL, 'options' => NULL, 'row' => NULL),
      'template' => ' views-view--gallery-content',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'nigel_gallery'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have added my code to my question, as it isn't working and I assuming I am missing something completely here. :)